# Insertion of value-pair in Hash for division calculation unexpectedly returning 0 in Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

In Ruby on Rails 3.2.1, I am iterating over the value pairs of a hash, where trsesh_mode is the key and trsesh_count is the value. I want to divide the trsesh_count for each mode of exercise the user had done by the total number of training sessions that user has completed.

Here is the iteration of the hash:

```
@trsesh_counts.each do |trsesh_mode, trsesh_count|
     count = @user_name.training_sessions.count 

     @weight =  trsesh_count / count
```

@weight is returning 0 for each value iterated into the calculation.

If I convert this calculation into a string and embed the ruby variables like so:

```
<% = "(#{trsesh_count}) / (#{count})" %>
```

... I get this output in my view:

```
(7) / (20)
(12) / (20)
(1) / (20)
```

where 20 is the count and the numerators are the iterated trsesh_count values.

If it helps, the trsesh_count values are FixNum.

My question is: Why am I getting 0 for output when performing the calculation above (@weight = ...)? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing integer numbers, so that the integer division result is zero.

Force one number to float, and it should work fine, like this:

```
@weight =  trsesh_count.to_f / count
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this worked. Didn't know that in Ruby, dividing two integers results in an integer.

Comment: Hey man, glad I could help. It's an awfully common source of headaches this division thing. In all programming languages I know, integers divided by integers will always yield integers, just remember that and you'll be fine ;)